# Jquery in aspx vs html

Tags: jquery, asp.net, checkboxlist

I have the following Jquery running in an aspx page without the use of a master page. The markup, with script is below. It works just fine.

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" Text="Check All" /><br />

    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cbList" runat="server">
    </asp:CheckBoxList>

</div>
</form>
```

Here is the script

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#chkAll').click(
         function () {
             $("INPUT[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', $('#chkAll').is(':checked'));
         });
    });    

 </script>
```

Here is the markup for the page i created using a master page. The master page only has the reference to the jquery file in the header in the HeadContent placeholder. Needless to say it doesnt work in the master page scenario. Why is the question

```
 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
   The identical script from above is placed here

</asp:Content>
```

And here is the placeholder content markup

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">

<div>

    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" Text="Check All" /><br />

    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cbList" runat="server">
    </asp:CheckBoxList>

</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ClientIDMode="Static"` on your control should allow you to reference it by the name you assigned.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" Text="Check All" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `ID` values you give to webform controls when they have `runat="server"` on them. The ID will be changed to something like `ctl1_chkAll` and your script will fail. You need to reference their client id with something like:

```
$("#<%= chkAll.ClientID %>")
```

... which is why people are moving away from webforms.

Answer (score 0):

This is because, the Control ID rendered on the page is different when we use the master page. You should do something like below to make sure the code works in both the cases.

```
$("[id$='chkAll']").click() { function () {
    $("INPUT[type='checkbox']").attr("checked", $(this).attr("checked"));
});
```

Hope this Helps!!

Comment: Bhamlin, Brenden and Praveen, thank you... all 3 solutions worked

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like an issue with the relative path to your jQuery script, you should use your web debugger (FireBug, IE Toolbar, etc...) to see if your script is loading.  If your Scripts folder is in the root of your site, set the script src to "/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js".

Comment: that is not the issue as stated the page at the top works perfectly fine, the page using a master does not. Each page has the same script source reference